# Dynamic alternative to pivot with CASE and GROUP BY

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, pivot-table, window-functions

I have a table that looks like this:

```
id    feh    bar
1     10     A
2     20     A
3      3     B
4      4     B
5      5     C
6      6     D
7      7     D
8      8     D
```

And I want it to look like this:

```
bar  val1   val2   val3
A     10     20 
B      3      4 
C      5        
D      6      7     8
```

I have this query that does this:

```
SELECT bar, 
   MAX(CASE WHEN abc."row" = 1 THEN feh ELSE NULL END) AS "val1",
   MAX(CASE WHEN abc."row" = 2 THEN feh ELSE NULL END) AS "val2",
   MAX(CASE WHEN abc."row" = 3 THEN feh ELSE NULL END) AS "val3"
FROM
(
  SELECT bar, feh, row_number() OVER (partition by bar) as row
  FROM "Foo"
 ) abc
GROUP BY bar
```

Is there a way to improve this query or write it more efficiently altogether?

Comment: If you can load the standard-contrib [tablefunc module](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/tablefunc.html), the crosstab function will do what you want.

Comment: @flipflop99 You can use PL/PgSQL to query for the entry with the most values and use `EXECUTE` with the `format` function to generate the CASE statements dynamically. Daniel is right that it's probably better to just use `crosstab` though.

Comment: @CraigRinger: I went into detail to explore "dynamic" possibilities with `crosstab()`.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

If you have not installed the additional module [**tablefunc**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tablefunc.html), run this command *once* per database:

```
CREATE EXTENSION tablefunc;
```

### Answer to question

A very basic crosstab solution for your case:

```sql
SELECT * FROM crosstab(
  'SELECT bar, 1 AS cat, feh
   FROM   tbl_org
   ORDER  BY bar, feh')
 AS ct (bar text, val1 int, val2 int, val3 int);  -- more columns?
```

The **special difficulty** here is, that there is no *category* (`cat`) in the base table. For the basic **1-parameter form** we can just provide a dummy column with a dummy value serving as category. The value is ignored anyway.

This is one of the **rare cases** where the **second parameter** for the `crosstab()` function is **not needed**, because all `NULL` values only appear in dangling columns to the right by definition of this problem. And the order can be determined by the *value*.

If we had an actual *category* column with names determining the order of values in the result, we'd need the **2-parameter form** of `crosstab()`. Here I synthesize a category column with the help of the window function [`row_number()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html), to base `crosstab()` on:

```sql
SELECT * FROM crosstab(
   $$
   SELECT bar, val, feh
   FROM  (
      SELECT *, 'val' || row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY bar ORDER BY feh) AS val
      FROM tbl_org
      ) x
   ORDER BY 1, 2
   $$
 , $$VALUES ('val1'), ('val2'), ('val3')$$         -- more columns?
) AS ct (bar text, val1 int, val2 int, val3 int);  -- more columns?
```

The rest is pretty much run-of-the-mill. Find more explanation and links in these closely related answers.

*Basics:*
<sub>***Read this first if you are not familiar with the `crosstab()` function!***</sub>

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)

*Advanced:*

- [Pivot on Multiple Columns using Tablefunc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15415446/pivot-on-multiple-columns-using-tablefunc/15421607#15421607)
- [Merge a table and a change log into a view in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10109564/merge-a-table-and-a-change-log-into-a-view-in-postgresql/10110519#10110519)

#### Proper test setup

The test setup that's missing in the question:

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE tbl_org (id int, feh int, bar text);
INSERT INTO tbl_org (id, feh, bar) VALUES
  (1, 10, 'A')
, (2, 20, 'A')
, (3,  3, 'B')
, (4,  4, 'B')
, (5,  5, 'C')
, (6,  6, 'D')
, (7,  7, 'D')
, (8,  8, 'D')
;
```

### Dynamic crosstab?

Not very *dynamic*, yet, as [@Clodoaldo commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15506199/dynamic-alternative-to-pivot-with-case-and-group-by/15514334#comment21984934_15514334). Dynamic return types are hard to achieve with plpgsql. But there *are* ways around it - *with some limitations*.

So not to further complicate the rest, I demonstrate with a ***simpler*** test case:

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE tbl (row_name text, attrib text, val int);
INSERT INTO tbl (row_name, attrib, val) VALUES
  ('A', 'val1', 10)
, ('A', 'val2', 20)
, ('B', 'val1', 3)
, ('B', 'val2', 4)
, ('C', 'val1', 5)
, ('D', 'val3', 8)
, ('D', 'val1', 6)
, ('D', 'val2', 7)
;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab('SELECT row_name, attrib, val FROM tbl ORDER BY 1,2')
AS ct (row_name text, val1 int, val2 int, val3 int);
```

Returns:

```
 row_name | val1 | val2 | val3
----------+------+------+------
 A        | 10   | 20   |
 B        |  3   |  4   |
 C        |  5   |      |
 D        |  6   |  7   |  8
```

#### Built-in feature of `tablefunc` module

The tablefunc module provides a simple infrastructure for generic `crosstab()` calls without providing a column definition list. A number of functions written in C (very fast):


```
crosstabN()
```

`crosstab1()` - `crosstab4()` are pre-defined. One minor point: they require and return all `text`. So we need to cast our `integer` values. But it simplifies the call:

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab4('SELECT row_name, attrib, val::text  -- cast!
                         FROM tbl ORDER BY 1,2')
```

Result:

| row_name | category_1 | category_2 | category_3 | category_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10 | 20 |  |  |
| B | 3 | 4 |  |  |
| C | 5 |  |  |  |
| D | 6 | 7 | 8 |  |

#### Custom `crosstab()` function

For ***more columns*** or ***other data types***, we create our own *composite type* and *function* (once).
Type:

```
CREATE TYPE tablefunc_crosstab_int_5 AS (
  row_name text, val1 int, val2 int, val3 int, val4 int, val5 int);
```

Function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION crosstab_int_5(text)
  RETURNS SETOF tablefunc_crosstab_int_5
AS '$libdir/tablefunc', 'crosstab' LANGUAGE c STABLE STRICT;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab_int_5('SELECT row_name, attrib, val   -- no cast!
                              FROM tbl ORDER BY 1,2');
```

Result:

| row_name | val1 | val2 | val3 | val4 | val5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10 | 20 |  |  |  |
| B | 3 | 4 |  |  |  |
| C | 5 |  |  |  |  |
| D | 6 | 7 | 8 |  |  |

### *One* polymorphic, dynamic function for all

*This goes beyond what's covered by the `tablefunc` module.*
To make the return type dynamic I use a polymorphic type with a technique detailed in this related answer:

- [Refactor a PL/pgSQL function to return the output of various SELECT queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740256/refactor-a-pl-pgsql-function-to-return-the-output-of-various-select-queries/11751557#11751557)

1-parameter form:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION crosstab_n(_qry text, _rowtype anyelement)
  RETURNS SETOF anyelement
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 
   (SELECT format('SELECT * FROM crosstab(%L) t(%s)'
                , _qry
                , string_agg(quote_ident(attname) || ' ' || atttypid::regtype
                           , ', ' ORDER BY attnum))
    FROM   pg_attribute
    WHERE  attrelid = pg_typeof(_rowtype)::text::regclass
    AND    attnum > 0
    AND    NOT attisdropped);
END
$func$;
```

Overload with this variant for the 2-parameter form:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION crosstab_n(_qry text, _cat_qry text, _rowtype anyelement)
  RETURNS SETOF anyelement
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 
   (SELECT format('SELECT * FROM crosstab(%L, %L) t(%s)'
                , _qry, _cat_qry
                , string_agg(quote_ident(attname) || ' ' || atttypid::regtype
                           , ', ' ORDER BY attnum))
    FROM   pg_attribute
    WHERE  attrelid = pg_typeof(_rowtype)::text::regclass
    AND    attnum > 0
    AND    NOT attisdropped);
END
$func$;
```

`pg_typeof(_rowtype)::text::regclass`: There is a row type defined for every user-defined composite type, so that attributes (columns) are listed in the system catalog [`pg_attribute`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-attribute.html). The fast lane to get it: cast the registered type (`regtype`) to `text` and cast this `text` to `regclass`.

#### Create composite types once

You need to define once every return type you are going to use:

```sql
CREATE TYPE tablefunc_crosstab_int_3 AS (
    row_name text, val1 int, val2 int, val3 int);

CREATE TYPE tablefunc_crosstab_int_4 AS (
    row_name text, val1 int, val2 int, val3 int, val4 int);

...
```

For ad-hoc calls, you can also just create a **temporary table** to the same (temporary) effect:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_xtype7 AS (
    row_name text, x1 int, x2 int, x3 int, x4 int, x5 int, x6 int, x7 int);
```

Or use the type of an existing table, view or materialized view if available.

#### Call

Using above row types:

1-parameter form (no missing values):

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab_n(
   'SELECT row_name, attrib, val FROM tbl ORDER BY 1,2'
 , NULL::tablefunc_crosstab_int_3);
```

2-parameter form (some values can be missing):

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab_n(
   'SELECT row_name, attrib, val FROM tbl ORDER BY 1'
 , $$VALUES ('val1'), ('val2'), ('val3')$$
 , NULL::tablefunc_crosstab_int_3);
```

This **one function** works for all return types, while the `crosstabN()` framework provided by the `tablefunc` module needs a separate function for each.
If you have named your types in sequence like demonstrated above, you only have to replace the bold number. To find the maximum number of categories in the base table:

```sql
SELECT max(count(*)) OVER () FROM tbl  -- returns 3
GROUP  BY row_name
LIMIT  1;
```

That's about as dynamic as this gets if you want *individual columns*. Arrays like [demonstrated by @Clocoaldo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15513319/939860) or a simple text representation or the result wrapped in a document type like `json` or `hstore` can work for any number of categories dynamically.

**Disclaimer:**
It's always potentially dangerous when user input is converted to code. Make sure this cannot be used for SQL injection. Don't accept input from untrusted users (directly).

#### Call for original question:

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab_n('SELECT bar, 1, feh FROM tbl_org ORDER BY 1,2'
                       , NULL::tablefunc_crosstab_int_3);
```

Comment: Not all that dynamic since the computed column names must be provided. And the OP says they can be many.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto: I dug deeper. You may be interested in the sizable update to my answer.

Comment: Yes very good, but still one must know the number of columns and create the types. I made it completely dynamic [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12989297/131874) but I have a genetic allergy to complexity so I think the array solution I gave for this question is much better if column names taken from the data are not required.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto: "Better" is defined by requirements.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto: I only just now realized your link under *here* that's referring to another answer. Very nice. Seems pretty useful for long lists of categories or ad-hoc queries. But it needs *two* queries. One to create the table, one to read from it. With two queries, one can make everything "dynamic". 1. build query string, 2. execute it. The challenge is to do it in a single query and SQL wants to know the return type up front.

Comment: One only query would be nice. But is seems not possible in the current state of `tablefunc` as you know by trying more than once. I guess the questions' authors do not care about number of queries as long as the performance is adequate for a given scenario. I don't remember why I opted for the anonymous block in that answer but I guess it could be a function and that would make it one only query.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto: No it wouldn't. Not for a dynamic result type. Try it. :)

Answer (score 24):

Although this is an old question, I would like to add another solution made possible by recent improvements in PostgreSQL.  This solution achieves the same goal of returning a structured result from a dynamic data set **without using the crosstab function at all.**  In other words, this is a good example of re-examining unintentional and implicit assumptions that prevent us from discovering new solutions to old problems. ;)

To illustrate, you asked for a method to transpose data with the following structure:

```
id    feh    bar
1     10     A
2     20     A
3      3     B
4      4     B
5      5     C
6      6     D
7      7     D
8      8     D
```

into this format:

```
bar  val1   val2   val3
A     10     20 
B      3      4 
C      5        
D      6      7     8
```

The conventional solution is a clever (and incredibly knowledgeable) approach to creating dynamic crosstab queries that is explained in exquisite detail in Erwin Brandstetter's answer.

However, if your particular use case is flexible enough to accept a slightly different result format, then another solution is possible that handles dynamic pivots beautifully.  This technique, which I learned of here

- [Dynamic Pivot Tables with JSON and PostgreSQL](http://bender.io/2016/09/18/dynamic-pivot-tables-with-json-and-postgresql/)

uses PostgreSQL's new [`jsonb_object_agg`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE) function to construct pivoted data on the fly in the form of a JSON object.

I will use Mr. Brandstetter's "simpler test case" to illustrate:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE tbl (row_name text, attrib text, val int);
INSERT INTO tbl (row_name, attrib, val) VALUES
   ('A', 'val1', 10)
 , ('A', 'val2', 20)
 , ('B', 'val1', 3)
 , ('B', 'val2', 4)
 , ('C', 'val1', 5)
 , ('D', 'val3', 8)
 , ('D', 'val1', 6)
 , ('D', 'val2', 7);
```

Using the `jsonb_object_agg` function, we can create the required pivoted result set with this pithy beauty:

```
SELECT
  row_name AS bar,
  json_object_agg(attrib, val) AS data
FROM tbl
GROUP BY row_name
ORDER BY row_name;
```

Which outputs:

```
 bar |                  data                  
-----+----------------------------------------
 A   | { "val1" : 10, "val2" : 20 }
 B   | { "val1" : 3, "val2" : 4 }
 C   | { "val1" : 5 }
 D   | { "val3" : 8, "val1" : 6, "val2" : 7 }
```

As you can see, this function works by creating key/value pairs in the JSON object from the `attrib` and `value` columns in the sample data, all grouped by `row_name`.

Although this result set obviously looks different, I believe it will actually satisfy many (if not most) real world use cases, especially those where the data requires a dynamically-generated pivot, or where resulting data is consumed by a parent application (e.g., needs to be re-formatted for transmission in a http response).

Benefits of this approach:

- **Cleaner syntax.**  I think everyone would agree that the syntax for this approach is far cleaner and easier to understand than even the most basic crosstab examples.
- **Completely dynamic.**  No information about the underlying data need be specified beforehand.  Neither the column names nor their data types need be known ahead of time.
- **Handles large numbers of columns.**  Since the pivoted data is saved as a single jsonb column, you will not run up against PostgreSQL's column limit (≤1,600 columns, I believe).  There is still a limit, but I believe it is the same as for text fields: 1 GB per JSON object created (please correct me if I am wrong).  That's a lot of key/value pairs!
- **Simplified data handling.**  I believe that the creation of JSON data in the DB will simplify (and likely speed up) the data conversion process in parent applications.  (You will note that the integer data in our sample test case was correctly stored as such in the resulting JSON objects.  PostgreSQL handles this by automatically converting its intrinsic data types to JSON in accordance with the JSON specification.) This will effectively eliminate the need to manually cast data passed to parent applications:  it can all be delegated to the application's native JSON parser.

Differences (and possible drawbacks):

- **It looks different.**  There's no denying that the results of this approach look different.  The JSON object is not as pretty as the crosstab result set; however, the differences are purely cosmetic.  The same information is produced--and in a format that is probably *more* friendly for consumption by parent applications.
- **Missing keys.**  Missing values in the crosstab approach are filled in with nulls, while the JSON objects are simply missing the applicable keys.  You will have to decide for your self if this is an acceptable trade off for your use case.  It seems to me that any attempt to address this problem in PostgreSQL will greatly complicate the process and likely involve some introspection in the form of additional queries.
- **Key order is not preserved.**  I don't know if this can be addressed in PostgreSQL, but this issue is mostly cosmetic also, since any parent applications are either unlikely to rely on key order, or have the ability to determine proper key order by other means.  The worst case will probably only require an addition query of the database.

**Conclusion**

I am very curious to hear the opinions of others (especially @ErwinBrandstetter's) on this approach, especially as it pertains to performance.  When I discovered this approach on Andrew Bender's blog, it was like getting hit in the side of the head.  What a beautiful way to take a fresh approach to a difficult problem in PostrgeSQL.  It solved my use case perfectly, and I believe it will likewise serve many others as well.

Comment: I built on your answer for completeness. http://stackoverflow.com/a/42041676/131874

Comment: Thanks for adding your expertise! I think this method is the best alternative to crosstabs when a dynamic query is need.

Comment: Any thoughts on how to order by a specific data key? Seems like it doesn't like the traditional `data->>key` operator due to data being an alias.

Comment: See Clodoaldo's excellent and comprehensive answer below: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/42041676/131874](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42041676/131874).

Comment: I just saw this just now. Like I wrote: `the result wrapped in a document type like json or hstore can work for any number of categories dynamically.` You implemented this with modern tools for `jsonb`. If a single aggregated result column is acceptable, the solution is great. (There are many similar, older answers around. [Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31552108/939860)) But table-functions returning truly dynamic columns are still impossible (incl. pg 10). Probably not going to change any time soon, the limitation is anchored in the strictly typed SQL language itself.

Comment: Solid answer. Curious, how to turn the JSON keys into columns now, as asked by the OP?

Comment: Just a note on the "Key order":

You can add ORDER BY to json_object_agg like:

json_object_agg(attrib, val ORDER BY attrib DESC) AS data

Answer (score 11):

This is to complete [@Damian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40093700/131874) good answer. I have already suggested the JSON approach in other answers before the 9.6's handy `json_object_agg` function. It just takes more work with the previous tool set.

Two of the cited possible drawbacks are really not. The random key order is trivially corrected if necessary. The missing keys, if relevant, takes an almost trivial amount of code to be addressed:

```
select
    row_name as bar,
    json_object_agg(attrib, val order by attrib) as data
from
    tbl
    right join
    (
        (select distinct row_name from tbl) a
        cross join
        (select distinct attrib from tbl) b
    ) c using (row_name, attrib)
group by row_name
order by row_name
;
 bar |                     data                     
-----+----------------------------------------------
 a   | { "val1" : 10, "val2" : 20, "val3" : null }
 b   | { "val1" : 3, "val2" : 4, "val3" : null }
 c   | { "val1" : 5, "val2" : null, "val3" : null }
 d   | { "val1" : 6, "val2" : 7, "val3" : 8 }
```

For a final query consumer which understands JSON there are no drawbacks. The only one is that it can not be consumed as a table source.

Comment: Is there a way to transform the JSON data to a table with columns?

Comment: @alearnerhasnoname ,  there is indeed a way to transform the JSON into a table. 
I'm working on a Q&A entry for JSON crosstab-pivots using the json_populate_recordset() method. Here's a dbfiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/Sn7iO4zL

Answer (score 4):

In your case I guess an array is good. [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/9a403/2)

```
select
    bar,
    feh || array_fill(null::int, array[c - array_length(feh, 1)]) feh
from
    (
        select bar, array_agg(feh) feh
        from foo
        group by bar
    ) s
    cross join (
        select count(*)::int c
        from foo
        group by bar
        order by c desc limit 1
    ) c(c)
;
 bar |      feh      
-----+---------------
 A   | {10,20,NULL}
 B   | {3,4,NULL}
 C   | {5,NULL,NULL}
 D   | {6,7,8}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry about returning in the past, but the solution "Dynamic Crosstab" returns erroneous result table. Thus, the valN values are erroneously "aligned to the left" and they don't correspond to the column names. When the input  table has "holes" in the values, e.g. "C" has val1 and val3 but not val2. This produces an error: val3 value will be ranged in the column val2 (i.e. the next free column) in the final table.

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE tbl (row_name text, attrib text, val int); 
INSERT INTO tbl (row_name, attrib, val) VALUES ('C', 'val1', 5) ('C', 'val3', 7);

SELECT * FROM crosstab('SELECT row_name, attrib, val FROM tbl 
ORDER BY 1,2') AS ct (row_name text, val1 int, val2 int, val3 int);

row_name|val1|val2|val3
 C      |   5|  7 |
```

In order to return correct cells with "holes" in the right column, the crosstab query requires a 2nd SELECT in the crosstab, something like this `"crosstab('SELECT row_name, attrib, val FROM tbl ORDER BY 1,2', 'select distinct row_name from tbl order by 1')"`

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really *dynamic* in the sense that you still have to enumerate as many columns as values you are anticipating, but it's easy enough to do that this way. The one gotcha is that the columns require an ordinal key to match, with no interruptions. Also, if there're duplicate keys, it'll throw it all out of whack, so de-duping is required as well. The sets would all have to be pre-partitioned to accommodate proper sets of N.

To me it looks kludgy, so not sure if it gets much bang for the buck. But I'm adding this to the community dogpile in the hopes it'll provide some foment for someone else to come up w/ a better approach.

```
/** build a dataset **/
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmpT ;
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmpT AS
SELECT
 NULL::INT AS key
 ,NULL::INT AS ints
 ,NULL::VARCHAR(1) AS chars
 ,NULL::VARCHAR(3) AS unnest
LIMIT 0 ;

insert into tmpT (key, ints, chars, unnest)
values   (1 , 1   , 'o',  CHR( 130 - 10 ) )       
        ,(2 , 2   , 'n',  CHR( 130 - 11 ) )       
        ,(3 , 3   , 'm',            NULL  )       
        --,(4 , 4   , 'l',  CHR( 130 - 13 ) ) -- missing set       
        ,(5 , 5   , null, CHR( 130 - 14 ) )        
        ,(6 , null, 'j',  CHR( 130 - 15 ) )        
        ,(7 , 7   , null, CHR( 130 - 16 ) )         
        ,(8 , null, 'h',  CHR( 130 - 17 ) )        
        ,(9 , 9   , null, CHR( 130 - 18 ) )         
        ,(10, null, 'f' ,           NULL  )        
        ,(11, null, 'a',  CHR( 130 - 20 ) )        
        ,(12, 12  , null, CHR( 130 - 21 ) )         
 ; /** end of build a dataset **/

/** set up full set of pivotal column positions, to backfill any missing  **/
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tGenSer ; 
CREATE TEMP TABLE tGenSer AS SELECT generate_series( 1, 1000 )::INT AS key ;
```

/** THEN THE PIVOT **/

```
/* Pivot 10 columns */
SELECT *
FROM     /* name the columns*/
(    SELECT a a ,a b ,a c ,a d ,a e ,a f ,a g ,a h ,a i ,a j /*,a k ,a l ,a m ,a n ,a o ,a p ,a q ,a r ,a s ,a t*/ /* ,a u ,a v ,a w ,a x ,a y ,a z*/ FROM ( SELECT NULL::VARCHAR(3) AS a /**seed the typed columns **/) a  
    
    UNION /** union is just a helper, to assign names to unnamed columns **/
    
    /** 20 columns **/
    SELECT * FROM
    (
        /* enumerate columns, no name */
        SELECT t1.x[1 ] ,t1.x[2 ] ,t1.x[3 ] ,t1.x[4 ] ,t1.x[5 ] ,t1.x[6 ] ,t1.x[7 ] ,t1.x[8 ] ,t1.x[9 ] ,t1.x[10] 
        FROM ( SELECT  ARRAY( SELECT  a.ints::TEXT  AS v   
                        FROM tGenSer tg /**backfill missing keys**/ 
                        LEFT JOIN tmpT a ON tg.key = a.key ORDER BY tg.key 
                        ) AS x 
             ) t1
        
        UNION ALL
        
        SELECT t1.x[1 ] ,t1.x[2 ] ,t1.x[3 ] ,t1.x[4 ] ,t1.x[5 ] ,t1.x[6 ] ,t1.x[7 ] ,t1.x[8 ] ,t1.x[9 ] ,t1.x[10] 
        FROM ( SELECT  ARRAY( SELECT  a.chars::TEXT AS v 
                        FROM tGenSer tg /**backfill missing keys**/ 
                        LEFT JOIN tmpT a ON tg.key = a.key ORDER BY tg.key 
                        ) AS x 
            ) t1
        
        UNION ALL
        
        SELECT t1.x[1 ] ,t1.x[2 ] ,t1.x[3 ] ,t1.x[4 ] ,t1.x[5 ] ,t1.x[6 ] ,t1.x[7 ] ,t1.x[8 ] ,t1.x[9 ] ,t1.x[10] 
        FROM ( SELECT  ARRAY( SELECT  a.unnest      AS v 
                        FROM tGenSer tg /**backfill missing keys**/ 
                        LEFT JOIN tmpT a ON tg.key = a.key 
                        ORDER BY tg.key 
                        ) AS x 
           ) t1
     ) a
)b
WHERE ( a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j) IS DISTINCT FROM ( NULL ,NULL ,NULL ,NULL ,NULL ,NULL ,NULL ,NULL ,NULL ,NULL )        

;
```

RESULTS:

```
+---+---+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
| a | b |c |d |e |f |g |h |i |j |
+---+---+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
| x | w |  |  |t |s |r |q |p |  |
| o | n |m |  |  |j |  |h |  |f |
| 1 | 2 |3 |  |5 |  |7 |  |9 |  |
+---+---+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
```