# SQL Query to retrieve table value as column

Tags: sql, postgresql, crosstab, postgresql-9.0

I have a table view as below:

```
(SELECT * FROM session_log_detail)
![Raw Data from table session_log_detail][1]

attr_name     attr_value     timestamp
A                123           1:20:45
B                234           1:20:45
C                567           1:20:45
D                234           1:20:45
A                098           2:58:20
B                478           2:58:20
"                 "              "
```

What I would like to do is retrieve data like:

```
A         B          C           D
123      234        567         234
098      478
```

Where the time stamp value should be equal for each row, If changed need to be on the next line. `attr_values` and `timestamp` are random values.

I have Postgres `SQL 9.0`.

Comment: Data types for your columns are missing.

Comment: Search for pivot or crosstab query.

Answer (score 1):

#### Tablefunc module

You are looking for "pivot" or "crosstab". If you haven't installed the additional module [**tablefunc**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/tablefunc.html) already, install it once per database. In PostgreSQL 9.1+ this has been simplified to:

```
CREATE EXTENSION tablefunc;
```

In older versions (including 9.0) you have to run the install script from the shell with a command like:

```
psql -d dbname -f SHAREDIR/contrib/tablefunc.sql
```

For version 9.0 under Debian, this would be:

```
psql -d dbname -f /usr/share/postgresql/9.0/contrib/tablefunc.sql
```

More info for [Postgres 9.0 in the fine manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/contrib.html).

#### Query

Could look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab(
       'SELECT ts, attr_name, attr_value
        FROM   session_log_detail
        ORDER  BY 1,2'

      ,$$VALUES ('A'::text), ('B'), ('C'), ('D')$$)
AS tbl ("ts" text, "A" int, "B" int, "c" int, "D" int);
```

I named your column `ts`, since `timestamp` is a function name in Postgres and should not be used as identifier.

Find more explanation and details in these related answers:
[PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)
[Dynamic alternative to pivot with CASE and GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15506199/dynamic-alternative-to-pivot-with-case-and-group-by/15514334#15514334)

Comment: Permission for running the script failed, "psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user".

Comment: Please suggest alternative, Do PIVOT require require any script installation prior?

Comment: @user1564173: Try running the install script as system user `postgres`: `sudo su postgres`.

Comment: Postgres is installed on a customized linux and most of the commands cannot be executed.

Is there a way to hide a row if condition is not matched?

I want to able to get a near output using

SELECT CASE WHEN attr_name = 'user:name' AND attr_name <> '%' THEN attr_value END "User Name" FROM table_name;

But the problem with this query is It displays more empty row and are not NULL.

Comment: @user1564173: As explained above, `CREATE EXTENSION` is for Postgres 9.1+. And for most extensions you need superuser privileges to install them. The db-user `postgres` is the default superuser. And for new questions start a new *question* please.