# Creating Postgres table out of variable table data

Tags: sql, postgresql, transform, transpose, database-table

I have a Postgres table of data that looks like this (ex.):

```
╔════╦═══════════╦════════════╗
║ ID ║ FieldName ║ FieldValue ║
╠════╬═══════════╬════════════╣
║ 66 ║ PO#       ║   11111111 ║
║ 66 ║ Zip       ║      01810 ║
║ 66 ║ Badge     ║   22222222 ║
║ 67 ║ PO#       ║    7777777 ║
║ 67 ║ Zip       ║      02144 ║
║ 67 ║ Badge     ║   99999999 ║
╚════╩═══════════╩════════════╝
```

My question is how to transform this table into a new table that looks like this:

```
╔════╦══════════╦════════╦══════════╗
║ ID ║  Field1  ║ Field2 ║  Field3  ║
╠════╬══════════╬════════╬══════════╣
║ 66 ║ 11111111 ║  01810 ║ 22222222 ║
║ 66 ║  7777777 ║  02144 ║ 99999999 ║
╚════╩══════════╩════════╩══════════╝
```

I need to do it entirely with Postgres syntax. Ideally I would be able to also dynamically figure out how many fields there were but that is a secondary need. For now, the assumption is that there would be three fields and I need to essentially transpose them into these new columns called Field#.

Comment: http://www.craigkerstiens.com/2013/06/27/Pivoting-in-Postgres/

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Lots of running scripts and blinking stuff and remote sites requesting more permission to run more scripts on that page, but not that much content.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: It's a pivot.  There is a workable technique in there amidst the pixie dust.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Yeah, there's that, too.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `crosstab()` function from the tablefunc module. Detailed instruction and links here (read first!):
[PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)

Your query could look like:

```
SELECT *
FROM   crosstab(
         'SELECT "ID", "FieldName", "FieldValue"
          FROM   tbl
          ORDER  BY 1'

         ,$$VALUES ('PO#'::text), ('Zip'), ('Badge')$$
       ) AS ct ("Section" text, "Field1" int, "Field2" int, "Field3" int);
```

To `dynamically figure out how many fields there were`, you would have to build the above statement dynamically. SQL demands to know the return type. Much more details under this related question:
[Dynamic alternative to pivot with CASE and GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15506199/dynamic-alternative-to-pivot-with-case-and-group-by)