# Show multiple columns from a group of records

Tags: sql, postgresql, multiple-columns, aggregation, crosstab

Given the table:

```
score | name | time | nick
1       'A'    1      'X' 
4       'A'    2      'X'
10      'A'    3      'X'
10      'A'    4      'X'
1       'A'    5      'X'
1       'B'    6      'Z' 
4       'C'    7      'Z'
```

I'd like to create an output with **multiple columns**, first one being the score and the others the **sum**(time) as `name||'_time_'::text||nick`.

So it will be:

```
score | A_time_X | B_time_Z
1       6          0
4       2          0
10      7          0
1       0          6  
4       0          7
```

The columns for each score show the sum of time when the GROUP `(score,name,nick)` is the same. More columns will be shown for other values of `nick`.

Would that be possible?

Comment: Please explain "*multiple columns, first one being the score and the others the sum(time) as name||'time'::text||nick*"

Comment: Score 1st column. then one more column  per each group (score,name,nick) with the value of sum(time). The column name will be: <name>_'time'_<nick>. name and nick replaced by each different combination. As the example above.

Comment: The last row of your result should probably read `4 0 0`, not `4 0 7`, since the source table has `name = 'C'` for that one.

Answer (score 2):

The `group by` part is easy enough.  After that, you're pivoting `A_time_X` and `B_time_Z`.  One way to pivot is a `case` construct:

```
select  score
,       coalesce(case when name = 'A' and nick = 'X' then sum(time) end,0) as A_time_X
,       coalesce(case when name = 'B' and nick = 'Z' then sum(time) end,0) as B_time_Z
from    Table1
group by
        score
,       name
,       nick
```

[Working example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/83b02/3/0)

For more pivoting options see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11751905/50552).

Comment: that works! Would it be possible to have it more dynamic? Like that, for each new name or time you would have to update the query manually. so like assuming name can be only {'A','B'} but nick might change (new records will show up!

Comment: Dynamic pivoting is complex in SQL.  The answer I linked at the bottom has some options.

Answer (score 0):

#### Poor man's pivot with `CASE`

I would aggregate in a subquery to simplify. Probably faster, too:

```
SELECT score
     , CASE WHEN name = 'A' AND nick = 'X' THEN sum_time ELSE 0 END AS a_x
     , CASE WHEN name = 'B' AND nick = 'Z' THEN sum_time ELSE 0 END AS b_z
FROM  (
   SELECT score, name, nick, COALESCE(sum(time), 0) AS sum_time
   FROM   table1
   GROUP  BY 1,2,3
   ) sub
ORDER  BY score, name, nick;
```

#### `crosstab()`

Read basic instructions here, first:

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)

Since `crosstab()` expects a *single* column for the *key* value, generate a unique key from the combination of `(name, nick)`:

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab(
   $$
   SELECT score
        , CASE WHEN name = 'A' AND nick = 'X' THEN 1
               WHEN name = 'B' AND nick = 'Z' THEN 2 END AS key
        , COALESCE(sum(time), 0) AS val
   FROM   table1
   WHERE (name = 'A' AND nick = 'X' OR
          name = 'B' AND nick = 'Z')   -- exclude rest (optional, faster)
   GROUP  BY name, nick, score
   ORDER  BY key, score;  -- (!) reversed order to get your untypical result
   $$
  ,'VALUES (1),(2)'       -- match key values in order
  ) AS t (score int, a_x int, b_z int);
```

Produces your result (except for your error in the last line).
Typically, however, you would want:

```
   ORDER  BY score, key;  -- (!) typical case
```

To get this result (all values for same score in one row):

```
score | A_time_X | B_time_Z
1       6          6
4       2          7
10      7          NULL
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b2013/9) without `crosstab()` because it's currently not possible to install additional modules there.

#### Dynamic query?

Hard to come by, [as @Andomar already comemnted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25589261/show-multiple-column-from-a-group-of-records-postgresql#comment39969665_25589451). See what's *possible* here:

- [Dynamic alternative to pivot with CASE and GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15506199/dynamic-alternative-to-pivot-with-case-and-group-by/15514334#15514334)