# How do I return a jsonb array and array of objects from my data?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4, jsonb

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
  id       serial PRIMARY KEY
, employee text UNIQUE NOT NULL
, data     jsonb
);
```

With the following data:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (employee, data)
VALUES
 ('Jim', '{"sales_tv": [{"value": 10, "yr": "2010", "loc": "us"}, {"value": 5, "yr": "2011", "loc": "europe"}, {"value": 40, "yr": "2012", "loc": "asia"}], "sales_radio": [{"value": 11, "yr": "2010", "loc": "us"}, {"value": 8, "yr": "2011", "loc": "china"}, {"value": 76, "yr": "2012", "loc": "us"}], "another_key": "another value"}'),
 ('Rob', '{"sales_radio": [{"value": 7, "yr": "2014", "loc": "japan"}, {"value": 3, "yr": "2009", "loc": "us"}, {"value": 37, "yr": "2011", "loc": "us"}], "sales_tv": [{"value": 4, "yr": "2010", "loc": "us"}, {"value": 18, "yr": "2011", "loc": "europe"}, {"value": 28, "yr": "2012", "loc": "asia"}], "another_key": "another value"}')
```

Notice that there are other keys in there besides just "sales_tv" and "sales_radio". For the queries below I just need to focus on "sales_tv" and "sales_radio".

I need to find all sales for Jim for 2012. Anything that starts with "sales_" and then put that in an object (just need the what the product sold is and the value). e.g.:

```
    employee   | sales_
    Jim        | {"sales_tv": 40, "sales_radio": 76}
```

I've got:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable,
  (SELECT l.key, l.value FROM mytable, lateral jsonb_each_text(data) AS l
    WHERE key LIKE 'sales_%') AS a,
  jsonb_to_recordset(a.value::jsonb) AS d(yr text, value float)
  WHERE mytable.employee = 'Jim'
  AND d.yr = '2012'
```

But I can't seem to even get just Jim's data. Instead I get:

```
employee | key         |  value
-------- |------       | -----
Jim      | sales_tv    |  [{"yr": "2010", "loc": "us", "value": 4}, {"yr": "2011", "loc": "europe", "value": 18}, {"yr": "2012", "loc": "asia", "value": 28}]
Jim      | sales_tv    |  [{"yr": "2010", "loc": "us", "value": 10}, {"yr": "2011", "loc": "europe", "value": 5}, {"yr": "2012", "loc": "asia", "value": 40}]
Jim      | sales_radio |  [{"yr": "2010", "loc": "us", "value": 11}, {"yr": "2011", "loc": "china", "value": 8}, {"yr": "2012", "loc": "us", "value": 76}]
```

Comment: The question is very clear and has all necessary details. But please make it ***one*** question per question. I answered the first. I suggest you remove the second (and post another question if it's still unclear).

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter...will do. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You treat the result of the first join as JSON, not as text string, so use [**`jsonb_each()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) instead of `jsonb_each_text()`:

```
SELECT t.employee, json_object_agg(a.k, d.value) AS sales
FROM   mytable t
JOIN   LATERAL jsonb_each(t.data) a(k,v) ON a.k LIKE 'sales_%'
JOIN   LATERAL jsonb_to_recordset(a.v) d(yr text, value float) ON d.yr = '2012'
WHERE  t.employee = 'Jim'  -- works because employee is unique
GROUP  BY 1;
```

`GROUP BY 1` is shorthand for `GROUP BY t.employee`.
Result:

```
employee | sales
---------+--------
Jim      | '{ "sales_tv" : 40, "sales_radio" : 76 }'
```

I also untangled and simplified your query.

[**`json_object_agg()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE) is instrumental in aggregating name/value pairs as JSON object. Optionally cast to `jsonb` if you need that - or use [`jsonb_object_agg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE) in Postgres 9.5 or later.

Using explicit `JOIN` syntax to attach conditions in their most obvious place.
**The same** without explicit `JOIN` syntax:

```
SELECT t.employee, json_object_agg(a.k, d.value) AS sales
FROM   mytable t
     , jsonb_each(t.data)      a(k,v) 
     , jsonb_to_recordset(a.v) d(yr text, value float)
WHERE  t.employee = 'Jim'
AND    a.k LIKE 'sales_%'
AND    d.yr = '2012'
GROUP  BY 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first query can be solved like this (shooting from the hip, no access to PG 9.4 here):

```
SELECT employee, json_object_agg(key, sales)::jsonb AS sales_
FROM (
  SELECT t.employee, j.key, sum((e->>'value')::int) AS sales
  FROM mytable t,
       jsonb_each(t.data) j,
       jsonb_array_elements(j.value) e
  WHERE t.employee = 'Jim'
    AND j.key like 'sales_%'
    AND e->>'yr' = '2012'
  GROUP BY t.employee, j.key) sub
GROUP BY employee;
```

The trick here is that you use `LATERAL` joins to "peel away" outer layers of the `jsonb` object to get at data deeper down. This query is assuming that Jim may have sales in multiple locations.

(Working on your query 2)