# Select table as json array

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have three tables in PostgreSQL: `A`, `B`, `C`.
I want to get a row from table `A` with a specific `id`, plus all records from tables `B` and `C` with matching `id` as aggregated JSON.

For example:

```
Table A                     Table B                Table C
---------------------------------------------------------------
id / colum1  / colum2       id/  colum 1          id / column1
1  someValue, somValue      1   someVal1           1   someVal1
                            1   someVal2           1   someVal2
```

The expected output for `id = 1` would be:

```
a.column1   a.column2       ARRAY_JSON_B              ARRAY_JSON_C       
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
someValue    someValue   [{colum1:'someVal1'},       [{colum1:'someVal1'},
                         {colum1:'someVal2'}]        {colum1:'someVal2'}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>This requires Postgres 9.3 or later.</sup>

#### Simple case

I suggest to use the simpler [**`json_agg()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE) that's meant for this purpose, in `LATERAL` joins:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   a
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (SELECT json_agg(b) AS array_json_b FROM b WHERE id = a.id) b ON true
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (SELECT json_agg(c) AS array_json_c FROM c WHERE id = a.id) c ON true
WHERE  id = 1;
```

`LEFT JOIN LATERAL ... ON true` keeps rows in the result that have no match on the left side of the join. Details:

- [What is the difference between LATERAL JOIN and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

Subtle difference: This query returns NULL where no match is found in `b` or `c`, [@stas' query with correlated subqueries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33507299/939860) returns an empty array instead. May or may not be important.

#### Actual answer

Your example in the question excludes the redundant `id` column in `b` and `c` from the result - which makes sense. To achieve this, you can't use @stas' simple correlated subquery. While it would still *work* for a single column instead of the whole row, it would lose the column name and produce a simple array. Also, it would not work for more than one column.

Use [**`json_object_agg()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE) for a *single* selected column (which also allows to chose the tag name freely):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   a
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT json_object_agg('colum1', colum1) AS array_json_b
   FROM   b WHERE id = a.id
   ) b ON true
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT json_object_agg('colum1', colum1) AS array_json_c
   FROM   c WHERE id = a.id
   ) c ON true
WHERE  id = 1;
```

Or use a subselect for *any* selection (`col1` and `col2` in this example):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   a
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT json_agg(x) AS array_json_b
   FROM  (SELECT col1, col2 FROM b WHERE id = a.id) x
   ) b ON true
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT json_agg(x) AS array_json_c
   FROM  (SELECT col1, col2 FROM c WHERE id = a.id) x
   ) c ON true
WHERE  id = 1;
```

Related:

- [Return multiple columns of the same row as JSON array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26486784/return-multiple-columns-of-the-same-row-as-json-array-of-objects/26486910#26486910)
- [How do I return a jsonb array and array of objects from my data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31549705/how-do-i-return-a-jsonb-array-and-array-of-objects-from-my-data/31552108#31552108)

Answer (score 2):

```
select
        a.*,
        to_json(array(select b from b where b.id = a.id)) array_json_b,
        to_json(array(select c from c where c.id = a.id)) array_json_c
    from a
        where
            a.id = 1;
```

I hope your Postgresql version is 9.3 or higher. There is a clever function `to_json` which can convert anything to json. So we take an array of all related rows from `b` and convert it. Same with `c`.

Comment: Yes, It worked for me!! You save me hours finding and trying! Thank You!!