# How to query the data in a join table by two sets of joined records?

Tags: postgresql

I've got three tables: `users`, `courses`, and `grades`, the latter of which joins `users` and `courses` with some metadata like the `user`'s `score` for the `course`. I've [created a SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7bdd7), though the site doesn't appear to be working at the moment. The schema looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE users(
  id INT,
  name VARCHAR,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
INSERT INTO users VALUES
  (1, 'Beth'),
  (2, 'Alice'),
  (3, 'Charles'),
  (4, 'Dave');

CREATE TABLE courses(
  id INT,
  title VARCHAR,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
INSERT INTO courses VALUES
  (1, 'Biology'),
  (2, 'Algebra'),
  (3, 'Chemistry'),
  (4, 'Data Science');

CREATE TABLE grades(
  id INT,
  user_id INT,
  course_id INT,
  score INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
INSERT INTO grades VALUES
  (1, 2, 2, 89),
  (2, 2, 1, 92),
  (3, 1, 1, 93),
  (4, 1, 3, 88);
```

I'd like to know how (if possible) to construct a query which specifies some `users.id` values (1, 2, 3) and `courses.id` values (1, 2, 3) and returns those users' `grades.score` values for those courses

```
| name    | Algebra | Biology | Chemistry |
|---------|---------|---------|-----------|
| Alice   |      89 |      92 |           |
| Beth    |         |      93 |        88 | 
| Charles |         |         |           |
```

In my application logic, I'll be receiving an array of `user_ids` and `course_ids`, so the query needs to select those users and courses dynamically by primary key. (The actual data set contains millions of users and tens of thousands of courses—the examples above are just a sample to work with.)

Ideally, the query would:

- use the course titles as dynamic attributes/column headers for the `users`' score data
- sort the row and column headers alphabetically
- include empty/`NULL` cells if the `user`-`course` pair has no `grades` relationship

I suspect I may need some combination of `JOIN`s and Postgresql's [`crosstab`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/tablefunc.html), but I can't quite wrap my head around it.

**Update:** learning that the terminology for this is "dynamic pivot", I found [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15506199/dynamic-alternative-to-pivot-with-case-and-group-by/15514334#15514334) which appears to be trying to solve a related problem in Postgres with `crosstab()`

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple pivot query should work here, since you only have 4 courses in your data set to pivot.

```
SELECT t1.name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t3.title = 'Biology'      THEN t2.score ELSE NULL END) AS Biology,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t3.title = 'Algebra'      THEN t2.score ELSE NULL END) AS Algebra,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t3.title = 'Chemistry'    THEN t2.score ELSE NULL END) AS Chemistry,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t3.title = 'Data Science' THEN t2.score ELSE NULL END) AS Data_Science
FROM users t1
LEFT JOIN grades t2
    ON t1.id = t2.user_id
LEFT JOIN courses t3
    ON t2.course_id = t3.id
GROUP BY t1.name
```

Follow the link below for a running demo.  I used MySQL because, as you have noticed, SQLFiddle seems to be perpetually busted the other databases.

## SQLFiddle

Comment: I'm sorry, the 4 users and courses was just a sample to work with. I neglected to specify that my actual data contains tens of thousands courses and millions of users (though I expect to `SELECT` only a few dozen courses and thousands of users at a time), so `SELECT`ing data for each course by title within the query is not an option—it will need to be dynamic. I've now tried to clarify that in the question body.

Comment: @SteveGrossi Then you will need to use dynamic SQL.  Try Googling for "dynamic sql pivot"

Comment: That terminology is helpful in searching for solutions, thanks!