# Converting multiple row values to column name using Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot

I have a table like this:

```
State city  year  series values
s1     c1   1980   se_1    1
s1     c1   1981   se_1    2
s1     c1   1982   se_1    3
s1     c1   1980   se_2    4
s1     c1   1981   se_2    5
s1     c1   1982   se_2    6

s1     c2   1980   se_1    1
s1     c2   1981   se_1    2
s1     c2   1982   se_1    3
s1     c2   1980   se_2    4
s1     c2   1981   se_2    5
s1     c2   1982   se_2    6

s2     c1   1980   se_1    1
s2     c1   1981   se_1    2
s2     c1   1982   se_1    3
s2     c1   1980   se_2    4
s2     c1   1981   se_2    5
s2     c1   1982   se_2    6

s2     c2   1980   se_1    1
s2     c2   1981   se_1    2
s2     c2   1982   se_1    3
s2     c2   1980   se_2    4
s2     c2   1981   se_2    5
s2     c2   1982   se_2    6
```

I want to transform into like

```
state city se_1_1980 se_1_1981 se_1_1982 se_2_1980 se_2_1981 se_2_1982
s1     c1    1           2         3     4           5         6
s1     c2    1           2         3     4           5         6
s2     c1    1           2         3     4           5         6
s2     c2    1           2         3     4           5         6
```

I tried to use case statements but am not able to achieve the  result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `CASE WHEN` with `MAX` function to make pivot table.

**TestDLL**

```
CREATE TABLE T(
    State VARCHAR(5),
    city VARCHAR(5),
    year  INT,
    series VARCHAR(5),
    values INT
);

INSERT INTO T VALUES ('s1','c1',1980,'se_1',1);
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('s1','c1',1981,'se_1',2);
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('s1','c1',1982,'se_1',3);
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('s1','c1',1980,'se_2',4);
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('s1','c1',1981,'se_2',5);
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('s1','c1',1982,'se_2',6);
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('s1','c2',1980,'se_1',1);
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('s1','c2',1981,'se_1',2);
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('s1','c2',1982,'se_1',3);
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('s1','c2',1980,'se_2',4);
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('s1','c2',1981,'se_2',5);
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('s1','c2',1982,'se_2',6);
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('s2','c1',1980,'se_1',1);
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('s2','c1',1981,'se_1',2);
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('s2','c1',1982,'se_1',3);
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('s2','c1',1980,'se_2',4);
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('s2','c1',1981,'se_2',5);
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('s2','c1',1982,'se_2',6);
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('s2','c2',1980,'se_1',1);
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('s2','c2',1981,'se_1',2);
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('s2','c2',1982,'se_1',3);
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('s2','c2',1980,'se_2',4);
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('s2','c2',1981,'se_2',5);
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('s2','c2',1982,'se_2',6);
```

**Query**

```
SELECT State,
       city,
       MAX(CASE WHEN series ='se_1' AND year = 1980 THEN "values" END) as se_1_1980,
       MAX(CASE WHEN series ='se_1' AND year = 1981 THEN "values" END) as se_1_1981,
       MAX(CASE WHEN series ='se_1' AND year = 1982 THEN "values" END) as se_1_1982,
       MAX(CASE WHEN series ='se_2' AND year = 1980 THEN "values" END) as se_2_1980,
       MAX(CASE WHEN series ='se_2' AND year = 1981 THEN "values" END) as se_2_1981,
       MAX(CASE WHEN series ='se_2' AND year = 1982 THEN "values" END) as se_2_1982 
FROM  T
GROUP BY 
       State,
       city
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=9365f9d632d41810bd17d3fdbc925ef2)

**NOTE**

Avoid use keyword to be your tables column name, like `values` or `year`...
you can use another name instead of that

Comment: No problem , glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

**Before**:

[stackoverflow.com: Dynamic alternative to pivot with CASE and GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15506199/dynamic-alternative-to-pivot-with-case-and-group-by)

If you can "json" better choose.

> ```
> with T0 as (
> SELECT
>   State,
>   city,
>   series || '_' || trim(both ' ' from to_char(year, '9999')) series_year,
>   max(values) values_max
> FROM T
> group by 
>   1,2,3
> order by 
>   1,2,3
> )
> select 
>   State,
>   city,
>   jsonb_object_agg(series_year, values_max) AS data_json
> from T0
> group by
>   1,2
> ```
>
> ```
> state | city | data_json                                                                                       
> :---- | :--- | :-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> s2    | c1   | {"se_1_1980": 1, "se_1_1981": 2, "se_1_1982": 3, "se_2_1980": 4, "se_2_1981": 5, "se_2_1982": 6}
> s2    | c2   | {"se_1_1980": 1, "se_1_1981": 2, "se_1_1982": 3, "se_2_1980": 4, "se_2_1981": 5, "se_2_1982": 6}
> s1    | c2   | {"se_1_1980": 1, "se_1_1981": 2, "se_1_1982": 3, "se_2_1980": 4, "se_2_1981": 5, "se_2_1982": 6}
> s1    | c1   | {"se_1_1980": 1, "se_1_1981": 2, "se_1_1982": 3, "se_2_1980": 4, "se_2_1981": 5, "se_2_1982": 6}
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=185cacd05900ae39073492fda5400eea)*

---

**User Crosstab**

**info**

> ```
> -- info
> SELECT
>   state  || '_' || city state_city,
>   series || '_' || trim(both ' ' from to_char(year, '9999')) series_year,
>   max(values) values_max
> FROM T
> group by 
>   1,2
> order by 
>   1,2
> ```
>
> ```
> state_city | series_year | values_max
> :--------- | :---------- | ---------:
> s1_c1      | se_1_1980   |          1
> s1_c1      | se_1_1981   |          2
> s1_c1      | se_1_1982   |          3
> s1_c1      | se_2_1980   |          4
> s1_c1      | se_2_1981   |          5
> s1_c1      | se_2_1982   |          6
> s1_c2      | se_1_1980   |          1
> s1_c2      | se_1_1981   |          2
> s1_c2      | se_1_1982   |          3
> s1_c2      | se_2_1980   |          4
> s1_c2      | se_2_1981   |          5
> s1_c2      | se_2_1982   |          6
> s2_c1      | se_1_1980   |          1
> s2_c1      | se_1_1981   |          2
> s2_c1      | se_1_1982   |          3
> s2_c1      | se_2_1980   |          4
> s2_c1      | se_2_1981   |          5
> s2_c1      | se_2_1982   |          6
> s2_c2      | se_1_1980   |          1
> s2_c2      | se_1_1981   |          2
> s2_c2      | se_1_1982   |          3
> s2_c2      | se_2_1980   |          4
> s2_c2      | se_2_1981   |          5
> s2_c2      | se_2_1982   |          6
> ```

**info**

> ```
> -- info
> SELECT distinct  series || '_' || trim(both ' ' from to_char(year, '9999')) series_year FROM T order by 1
> ```
>
> ```
> | series_year |
> | :---------- |
> | se_1_1980   |
> | se_1_1981   |
> | se_1_1982   |
> | se_2_1980   |
> | se_2_1981   |
> | se_2_1982   |
> ```

> ```
> with T2 as(
> select 
>   *
> from crosstab(
>   '
> SELECT
>   state  || ''_'' || city state_city,
>   series || ''_'' || trim(both '' '' from to_char(year, ''9999'')) series_year,
>   max(values) values_max
> FROM T group by 1,2 order by 1,2',
>   'SELECT distinct series || ''_'' || trim(both '' '' from to_char(year, ''9999'')) series_year FROM T order by 1'
>   )
> as newtable (
>   state_city text,
>   se_1_1980 text,
>   se_1_1981 text,
>   se_1_1982 text,
>   se_2_1980 text,
>   se_2_1981 text,
>   se_2_1982 text
>   )
> )
> select 
>   split_part(state_city,'_',1) state,
>   split_part(state_city,'_',2) city,
>   se_1_1980,
>   se_1_1981,
>   se_1_1982,
>   se_2_1980,
>   se_2_1981,
>   se_2_1982
> from T2
> ```
>
> ```
> state | city | se_1_1980 | se_1_1981 | se_1_1982 | se_2_1980 | se_2_1981 | se_2_1982
> :---- | :--- | :-------- | :-------- | :-------- | :-------- | :-------- | :--------
> s1    | c1   | 1         | 2         | 3         | 4         | 5         | 6        
> s1    | c2   | 1         | 2         | 3         | 4         | 5         | 6        
> s2    | c1   | 1         | 2         | 3         | 4         | 5         | 6        
> s2    | c2   | 1         | 2         | 3         | 4         | 5         | 6
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=560b19a537058c95ce7c700bce5d7d8f)*

Comment: I want like se_1_ 1980 as a column with respect to value

Comment: @2SRTVF . . . Interesting solution.  If I were to use Postgres specific functionality, I think my first thought would be `crosstab`.