# Create Postgres Pivot like excel

Tags: postgresql, pivot

I need help with creating a pivot table. I've already tried many offered solutions here but I am stuck. Hope someone can help. Here's my scenario:

***Table1 sample***

```
ID              text    2712cb957
document_key    text    201808
```

***Table2 sample***

```
ID          text    2712cb957
amount_net  int     56000
classid     int     4021
```

***Table3 (from Table1 and Table2 via inner join ID)***
document_key    amount_net  classid

```
201808          10          4021
201808          10          4021
201808          15          4023
201808          13          4023
201807          20          4021
201807          15          4021
…               …           …
```

***Expected pivot table***

```
document_key    4021    4023
201807          35      0
201808          20      28
```

[image]

Comment: sry, this is my 1st post here. pls click on the image link for details. thx

Comment: Do you know in advance that you just want `4021` and `4023`? Or will this be dynamic based on however many distinct `classid`  exist in your table?

Comment: hi, there will be more class ids, so yes this should be dynamic

Comment: No worries on the formatting on all that. To preserve your whitespace and line feeds, just indent each line of your tables/code with 4 spaces. You can also highlight the block and hit the `{}` button at the top of the editor. I've made the edit to this question to do just that.

Comment: I noticed ;-), that's kind of you, appreciate it !

Comment: Dynamic Pivot in Postgres is not at all easy. There is a GREAT [write up at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15506199/dynamic-alternative-to-pivot-with-case-and-group-by/15514334#15514334) though that walks you through the `crosstab` keyword, how to apply it, and the steps necessary to make something that is dynamic. It's one of those things where you either dive into functions, or you generate a crosstab/pivot query dynamically and then execute the dynamically generated sql.

Comment: Generally dynamic pivot/crosstab output is best pushed to your application layer (if one exists). This is a place that client reporting software excels (like tableau, business objects(?I think), excel, etc...)

Comment: thx, what would the static solution look like, say with only 5 classids. I am using Pentaho Kettle - this is where all the ETL is happening....

Comment: Sorry for the delay. [This is a good simple example of a static crosstab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=db2998aa171dd9c0d7381599f5c37c79)

A **static** pivot could look like this:

---

**Postgres 9.4+**

Postgres 9.4 adds the `FILTER` function:

```
SELECT 
    document_key, 
    COALESCE(SUM(amount_net) FILTER (WHERE classid = 4021), 0) as "4021", -- A
    COALESCE(SUM(amount_net) FILTER (WHERE classid = 4023), 0) as "4023"
FROM test 
GROUP BY document_key
ORDER BY document_key
```

A: `GROUP BY document_key` aggregates all `document_key` groups. With the aggregate function `SUM` you add all corresponding `amount_net` values. The `FILTER` function is used to sum only these values from the rows containing `classid = XYZ`. The `COALESCE` around the aggregate makes `NULL` values to 0.

If you want more columns you have to copy this line of code.

---

**Postgres 9.3** and lower

```
SELECT 
    document_key, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN classid = 4021 THEN amount_net ELSE 0 END) as "4021", 
    SUM(CASE WHEN classid = 4023 THEN amount_net ELSE 0 END) as "4023"
FROM test 
GROUP BY document_key
ORDER BY document_key
```

Comment: Thanx, your sample throws a syntax error at the first occurance of FILTER

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: we're using 9.3

Comment: You should really upgrade your database since 9.3 is not longer supported. And you miss many really great features. Nevertheless: Added a more compatible version of the pivot and updated the fiddle

Comment: and how do I do that?

Comment: @HeikoO if that helped please don't forget to upvote as well (next to the green accept hook)