# Is there any way where I can do ALIAS reference other column value?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot-table, alias

I am trying to figure out how to do ALIAS which referring the value of other column.

I am not sure it is possible, but does it acquire some tricks to make it done?

How can I perform query something like code below?

```
SELECT chd_value AS **chd_key value**
FROM table1 where chd_id = 1;
```

where the chd_key will be replaced with the value of "chd_key" column in the table.

[image: Table1]

So I will get output similar like

[image: this].

Comment: Are you planning on running the raw query in DB console or are you using a library like PDO for PHP?

Comment: Hi, I am planning to run it on PHP

Comment: Postgres or MySQL? Please disclose your RDBMS and version. And remove the other tag. Solutions differ.

Comment: I am sorry . It is Postgresql.

Comment: `SELECT version();` helps ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will not give you two rows like you show in your image, but if you just want the key/value pair in a single column, do a concatenation on your key/value pair:

```
SELECT (chd_key || ':' || chd_value) AS chd_pair
FROM table1 WHERE chd_id = 1;
```

To add double quotes in a quick and dirty fashion as requested:

```
SELECT ('"' || chd_key || '":"' || chd_value || '"') AS chd_pair
FROM table1 WHERE chd_id = 1;
```

It's not pretty, but it's easy and it works.

Comment: Thanks, I will try your code. I will update my progress soon.

Comment: Sorry late response. I will accept your answer if you can help me out to include double quotes in between value and key , example "food":"chicken" . :D thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The key word is "pivoting" or "cross tabulation".

For a limited, known number of distinct values in `chd_key` the fastest technique is `crosstab()`. Like:

```
SELECT *
FROM   crosstab(
   'SELECT chd_id, chd_key, chd_value
    FROM   tbl
    where  chd_id = 1
    ORDER  BY 1'  -- ORDER BY redundant in this special case
  , $$VALUES ('food'), ('color'), ('gadget')$$
   ) AS ct (chd_id int, food text, color text, gadget text);
```

Detailed instructions:

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)

But that's not fully dynamic, which is hard to accomplish with SQL. See:

- [Dynamic alternative to pivot with CASE and GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15506199/dynamic-alternative-to-pivot-with-case-and-group-by/15514334#15514334)

---

One way to simply get `"key":"value"` like you later commented:

```
SELECT format('"%s":"%s"', chd_key, chd_value) AS chd_pair
FROM tbl WHERE chd_id = 1;
```

Comment: I would never take this much effort for non-production code, but the second portion of this answer is definitely more idiomatic than my own.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments the author intends to use PHP, PDO can be used to obtain the desired output. For example, assuming `$pdo` is a PDO instance:

```
 $pdo->query('SELECT chd_key, chd_value FROM table1 where chd_id = 1')
     ->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR)
```

The above will result in an associate array with the expected output. The first column used as the key and the second as the value:

```
[
  'food' => 'chiken'
]
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php