# How to create a comparison chart with feature count in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, pivot-table

I have OpenStreetMap data loaded to a PostgreSQL table. A hstore type column contains all of the  tags. I would like to make a comparison chart to see how many records has `name, name:en, name:bg` tags for example. The result I would like to see is something like this:

[image]

I can achieve this manually using this query:

```
SELECT 1 AS id, '+'  AS name, NULL AS "name:en", NULL AS "name:bg", count(*) FROM public.ways WHERE exist(tags,'name')      UNION
SELECT 2 AS id, NULL AS name, '+'  AS "name:en", NULL AS "name:bg", count(*) FROM public.ways WHERE exist(tags,'name:en')   UNION
SELECT 3 AS id, NULL AS name, NULL AS "name:en", '+'  AS "name:bg", count(*) FROM public.ways WHERE exist(tags,'name:bg')   UNION
SELECT 4 AS id, '+'  AS name, '+'  AS "name:en", NULL AS "name:bg", count(*) FROM public.ways WHERE exist(tags,'name')      AND exist(tags,'name:en')       UNION
SELECT 5 AS id, '+'  AS name, NULL AS "name:en", '+'  AS "name:bg", count(*) FROM public.ways WHERE exist(tags,'name')      AND exist(tags,'name:bg')       UNION
SELECT 6 AS id, '+'  AS name, '-'  AS "name:en", NULL AS "name:bg", count(*) FROM public.ways WHERE exist(tags,'name')      AND NOT exist(tags,'name:en')   UNION
SELECT 7 AS id, '-'  AS name, '+'  AS "name:en", NULL AS "name:bg", count(*) FROM public.ways WHERE NOT exist(tags,'name')  AND exist(tags,'name:en')
ORDER  BY id
```

I consider this unnecessarily long and overcomplicated, plus I have to do it manually. I know there are some possibilities using the crosstab function, but I couldn't get it working. Based on [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15506199/dynamic-alternative-to-pivot-with-case-and-group-by/15514334#15514334) I was able to create something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab(
    'SELECT tags::text~''"name"=>".*"'' as a, tags::text~''"name:en"=>".*"'' as b, tags::text~''"name_int"=>".*"'' as c FROM public.ways') 
AS ct (name boolean,"name:en" boolean, "name:bg" boolean)
GROUP BY name,"name:en","name:bg"
```

[image]

My problem is that I cannot seem to add a count column to this, and that it does not contain options where only one of the three condition is taken into account.

Any idea how could I solve this problem, or any direction where should I start?

Example data lines:

```
1 "name"=>"dm"
2 "name"=>"Ешекчи дере", "name:en"=>"Khatak Dere River"
3 "name:en"=>"Sushitsa"
4 "name"=>"Слънчева", "name:bg"=>"Слънчева", "name:en"=>"Slantcheva"
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello look if its works for you , it is possible to generate a join from a emulated table from a select to group the values :

```
SELECT row_number() OVER() AS id ,COUNT(*) AS count , COALESCE(a.tags , '')||COALESCE(b.tags,'')||COALESCE(c.tags ,'') AS tagcombination, 
CASE WHEN  COALESCE(a.tags , '')||COALESCE(b.tags,'')||COALESCE(c.tags ,'')="name:en" THEN '+'
WHEN  COALESCE(a.tags , '')||COALESCE(b.tags,'')||COALESCE(c.tags ,'')  = 'name:en' THEN '+' END AS name 

FROM public.ways AS a 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT tags FROM public.ways WHERE tags = 'name' ) AS b ON a.tags = b.tags 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT tags FROM public.ways WHERE tags IN('name:en', 'name:bg' )  )  AS c ON a.tags = c.tags 
JOIN (SELECT generate_series )
GROUP BY tagcombination
--WHERE a.tags IS NOT NULL 
--ORDER BY name
```

The name column could be translated into numbers from the tagscombination and even be ordered later if it fits better your relatory.
Need to do the test and use a predicate to filter if there is more values possibilities than you want to count in the table also.