# PIVOT VIEW using PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, case, crosstab

I'm new to PostgreSQL and am using version 9.4. I'm having a table with collected measurements as **strings** and need to convert it to a kind of PIVOT table using something which is always up-to-date, like a VIEW.
Furthermore, some values need to be converted, e. g. multiplied by 1000, as you
can see in the example below for "sensor3".

Source Table:

```
CREATE TABLE source (
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    name character varying(255),
    "timestamp" timestamp without time zone,
    value character varying(32672),
    CONSTRAINT source_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO source VALUES
  (15,'sensor2','2015-01-03 22:02:05.872','88.4')
, (16,'foo27'  ,'2015-01-03 22:02:10.887','-3.755')
, (17,'sensor1','2015-01-03 22:02:10.887','1.1704')
, (18,'foo27'  ,'2015-01-03 22:02:50.825','-1.4')
, (19,'bar_18' ,'2015-01-03 22:02:50.833','545.43')
, (20,'foo27'  ,'2015-01-03 22:02:50.935','-2.87')
, (21,'sensor3','2015-01-03 22:02:51.044','6.56');
```

Source Table Result:

```
| id | name      | timestamp                 | value    |
|----+-----------+---------------------------+----------|
| 15 | "sensor2" | "2015-01-03 22:02:05.872" | "88.4"   |
| 16 | "foo27"   | "2015-01-03 22:02:10.887" | "-3.755" |
| 17 | "sensor1" | "2015-01-03 22:02:10.887" | "1.1704" |
| 18 | "foo27"   | "2015-01-03 22:02:50.825" | "-1.4"   |
| 19 | "bar_18"  | "2015-01-03 22:02:50.833" | "545.43" |
| 20 | "foo27"   | "2015-01-03 22:02:50.935" | "-2.87"  |
| 21 | "sensor3" | "2015-01-03 22:02:51.044" | "6.56"   |
```

Desired Final Result:

```
| timestamp                 | sensor1 | sensor2 | sensor3 | foo27   | bar_18  |
|---------------------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------|
| "2015-01-03 22:02:05.872" |         | 88.4    |         |         |         |
| "2015-01-03 22:02:10.887" | 1.1704  |         |         | -3.755  |         |
| "2015-01-03 22:02:50.825" |         |         |         | -1.4    |         |
| "2015-01-03 22:02:50.833" |         |         |         |         | 545.43  |
| "2015-01-03 22:02:50.935" |         |         |         | -2.87   |         |
| "2015-01-03 22:02:51.044" |         |         | 6560.00 |         |         |
```

Using this:

```
--    CREATE EXTENSION tablefunc;
SELECT *
    FROM
        crosstab(
            'SELECT
                source."timestamp",
                source.name,
                source.value
            FROM
                public.source
            ORDER BY
                1'
            ,
            'SELECT
                DISTINCT
                source.name
            FROM
                public.source
            ORDER BY
                1'
        )
    AS
        (
            "timestamp" timestamp without time zone,
            "sensor1" character varying(32672),
            "sensor2" character varying(32672),
            "sensor3" character varying(32672),
            "foo27" character varying(32672),
            "bar_18" character varying(32672)
        )
    ;
```

I got the result:

```
| timestamp                 | sensor1 | sensor2 | sensor3 | foo27   | bar_18  |
|---------------------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------|
| "2015-01-03 22:02:05.872" |         |         |         | 88.4    |         |
| "2015-01-03 22:02:10.887" |         | -3.755  | 1.1704  |         |         |
| "2015-01-03 22:02:50.825" |         | -1.4    |         |         |         |
| "2015-01-03 22:02:50.833" | 545.43  |         |         |         |         |
| "2015-01-03 22:02:50.935" |         | -2.87   |         |         |         |
| "2015-01-03 22:02:51.044" |         |         |         |         | 6.56    |
```

Unfortunately,

1. the values aren't assigned to the correct column,
2. the columns aren't dynamic; that means the query fails when there is an additional entry in the name column like 'sensor4' and
3. I don't know how to change the values of some columns (multiply).

Comment: why `varchar(32672)`  why not `float` or `numeric`?

Comment: you need abother table that has matches the name to the source table and has the scale factor and desired column ordering, hten drop the 'as' clause.

Comment: @Jasen:
Not invented here!

Comment: woah! a blast from the past. are you still using 9.4?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your query works like this:

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab(
  $$SELECT "timestamp", name
         , CASE name
           WHEN 'sensor3' THEN value::numeric * 1000
       --  WHEN 'sensor9' THEN value::numeric * 9000  -- add more ...
           ELSE value::numeric END AS value
    FROM   source
    ORDER  BY 1, 2$$
 ,$$SELECT unnest('{bar_18,foo27,sensor1,sensor2,sensor3}'::text[])$$
) AS (
  "timestamp" timestamp
, bar_18  numeric
, foo27   numeric
, sensor1 numeric
, sensor2 numeric
, sensor3 numeric);
```

To multiply the `value` for selected columns use a ["simple" `CASE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE) statement. But you need to cast to a [numeric type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html) first. Using `value::numeric` in the example.
Which begs the question: Why not store value as numeric type to begin with?

You need to use the version with **two parameters**. Detailed explanation:

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)

**Truly dynamic** cross tabulation tables is **next to impossible**, since SQL demands to know the result type in advance - at call time at the latest. But you can do *something* with polymorphic types:

- [Dynamic alternative to pivot with CASE and GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15506199/dynamic-alternative-to-pivot-with-case-and-group-by/15514334#15514334)

Answer (score 1):

@Erwin: It said "too long by 7128 characters" for a comment! Anyway:

Your post gave me the hints for the right direction, so thank you very much,
but particularly in my case I need it be truly dynamic. Currently I've got
38886 rows with 49 different items (= columns to be pivoted).

To first answer yours and @Jasen's urgent question:
The source table layout is not up to me, I'm already very happy to get this
data into an RDBMS. If it were to me, I'd always save UTC-timestamps! But
there's also a reason for having the data saved as strings: it may contain
various data types, like boolean, integer, float, string etc.

To avoid confusing me further I created a new demo dataset, prefixing the data
type (I know some hate this!) to avoid problems with keywords and changing the
timestamp (--> minutes) for better overview:

```
--  --------------------------------------------------------------------------
--  Create demo table of given schema and insert arbitrary data
--  --------------------------------------------------------------------------

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_source;

    CREATE TABLE table_source
    (
        column_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
        column_name CHARACTER VARYING(255),
        column_timestamp TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE,
        column_value CHARACTER VARYING(32672),
        CONSTRAINT table_source_pkey PRIMARY KEY (column_id)
    );

    INSERT INTO table_source VALUES ( 15,'sensor2','2015-01-03 22:01:05.872','88.4');
    INSERT INTO table_source VALUES ( 16,'foo27' ,'2015-01-03 22:02:10.887','-3.755');
    INSERT INTO table_source VALUES ( 17,'sensor1','2015-01-03 22:02:10.887','1.1704');
    INSERT INTO table_source VALUES ( 18,'foo27' ,'2015-01-03 22:03:50.825','-1.4');
    INSERT INTO table_source VALUES ( 19,'bar_18','2015-01-03 22:04:50.833','545.43');
    INSERT INTO table_source VALUES ( 20,'foo27' ,'2015-01-03 22:05:50.935','-2.87');
    INSERT INTO table_source VALUES ( 21,'seNSor3','2015-01-03 22:06:51.044','6.56');

    SELECT * FROM table_source;
```

Furthermore based on @Erwin's suggestions I created a view which already
converts the data type. This has the nice feature, beside being fast, to only
add required transformations for known items, but not impacting other (new)
items.

```
--  --------------------------------------------------------------------------
--  Create view to process source data
--  --------------------------------------------------------------------------

    DROP VIEW IF EXISTS view_source_processed;

    CREATE VIEW
        view_source_processed
    AS
        SELECT
            column_timestamp,
            column_name,
            CASE LOWER( column_name)
                WHEN LOWER( 'sensor3') THEN CAST( column_value AS DOUBLE PRECISION) * 1000.0
                ELSE CAST( column_value AS DOUBLE PRECISION)
            END AS column_value
        FROM
            table_source
    ;

    SELECT * FROM view_source_processed ORDER BY column_timestamp DESC LIMIT 100;
```

This is the desired result of the whole question:

```
--  --------------------------------------------------------------------------
--  Desired result:
--  --------------------------------------------------------------------------

/*
| column_timestamp          | bar_18  | foo27   | sensor1 | sensor2 | seNSor3 |
|---------------------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------|
| "2015-01-03 22:01:05.872" |         |         |         |    88.4 |         |
| "2015-01-03 22:02:10.887" |         |  -3.755 |  1.1704 |         |         |
| "2015-01-03 22:03:50.825" |         |    -1.4 |         |         |         |
| "2015-01-03 22:04:50.833" |  545.43 |         |         |         |         |
| "2015-01-03 22:05:50.935" |         |   -2.87 |         |         |         |
| "2015-01-03 22:06:51.044" |         |         |         |         |    6560 |
*/
```

This is @Erwin's solution, adopted to the new demo source data. It's perfect,
as long as the items (= columns to be pivoted) doesn't change:

```
--  --------------------------------------------------------------------------
--  Solution by Erwin, modified for changed demo dataset:
--  http://stackoverflow.com/a/27773730
--  --------------------------------------------------------------------------

SELECT *
    FROM
        crosstab(
            $$
                SELECT
                    column_timestamp,
                    column_name,
                    column_value
                FROM
                    view_source_processed
                ORDER BY
                    1, 2
            $$
        ,
            $$
                SELECT
                    UNNEST( '{bar_18,foo27,sensor1,sensor2,seNSor3}'::text[])
            $$
        )
    AS
        (
            column_timestamp timestamp,
            bar_18  DOUBLE PRECISION,
            foo27   DOUBLE PRECISION,
            sensor1 DOUBLE PRECISION,
            sensor2 DOUBLE PRECISION,
            seNSor3 DOUBLE PRECISION
        )
    ;
```

When reading through the links @Erwin provided, I found a Dynamic SQL example
by @Clodoaldo Neto and remembered, that I had already done it this way in
Transact-SQL; this is my attempt:

```
--  --------------------------------------------------------------------------
--  Dynamic attempt based on:
--  http://stackoverflow.com/a/12989297/131874
--  --------------------------------------------------------------------------

DO $DO$

DECLARE
    list_columns TEXT;

    BEGIN

        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_table_pivot;

        list_columns := (
            SELECT
                string_agg( DISTINCT column_name, ' ' ORDER BY column_name)
            FROM
                view_source_processed
        );

        EXECUTE(
            FORMAT(
                $format_1$
                CREATE TEMP TABLE
                    temp_table_pivot(
                        column_timestamp TIMESTAMP,
                        %1$s
                    )
                $format_1$
            ,
                (
                    REPLACE(
                        list_columns,
                        ' ',
                        ' DOUBLE PRECISION, '
                    ) || ' DOUBLE PRECISION'
                )
            )
        );

        EXECUTE(
            FORMAT(
                $format_2$
                    INSERT INTO temp_table_pivot
                        SELECT
                            *
                        FROM crosstab(
                            $crosstab_1$
                            SELECT
                                column_timestamp,
                                column_name,
                                column_value
                            FROM
                                view_source_processed
                            ORDER BY
                                column_timestamp, column_name
                            $crosstab_1$
                        ,
                            $crosstab_2$
                            SELECT DISTINCT
                                column_name
                            FROM
                                view_source_processed
                            ORDER BY
                                column_name
                            $crosstab_2$
                        )
                        AS
                        (
                            column_timestamp TIMESTAMP,
                            %1$s
                        );
                $format_2$
            ,
                REPLACE( list_columns, ' ', ' DOUBLE PRECISION, ')
                ||
                ' DOUBLE PRECISION'
            )
        );

    END;

$DO$;

SELECT * FROM temp_table_pivot ORDER BY column_timestamp DESC LIMIT 100;
```

Beside getting this into a stored procedure, I will, for performance reasons,
try to adopt this to an intermediate table where only new values are inserted.
I'll keep you up-to-date!

Thanks!!!

L.

PS: NO, I don't want to answer my own question, but the "comment"-field is too small!