# how to preserve column names on dynamic pivot

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, plpgsql, postgresql-9.1

Sales data contains dynamic product names which can contian any characters.

Dynamic pivot table is created based on sample from 
[Crosstab with a large or undefined number of categories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12988575/crosstab-with-a-large-or-undefined-number-of-categories)

translate() is used to remove bad characters.

In result pivot table column names are corrupted: missing characters and spaces are removed.
How to return data with same column names as in source data ?
I tried to use

```
  quote_ident(productname) as tootjakood,
```

instead of

```
  'C'||upper(Translate(productname,'Ø. &/+-,%','O')) as tootjakood,
```

but it returns error

ERROR:  column "Ø, 12.3/3mm" does not exist

testcase:

```
create temp table sales ( saledate date, productname char(20), quantity int );
insert into sales values ( '2016-1-1', 'Ø 12.3/3mm', 2);
insert into sales values ( '2016-1-1', '+-3,4%/3mm', 52);
insert into sales values ( '2016-1-3', '/3,2m-', 246);

do $do$


declare
voter_list text;
begin

create temp table myyk on commit drop as
select saledate as kuupaev,
  'C'||upper(Translate(productname,'Ø. &/+-,%','O')) as tootjakood, 
  sum(quantity)::int as kogus 
from sales
group by 1,2
;

drop table if exists pivot;

voter_list := (
    select string_agg(distinct tootjakood, ' ' order by tootjakood) from myyk
    );

execute(format('
    create table pivot (
kuupaev date,
        %1$s
    )', (replace(voter_list, ' ', ' integer, ') || ' integer')
));

execute (format($f$

  insert into pivot
        select
           kuupaev,
            %2$s
        from crosstab($ct$
            select
                kuupaev,tootjakood,kogus
            from myyk
            order by 1
            $ct$,$ct$
            select distinct tootjakood
            from myyk
            order by 1
            $ct$
        ) as (
            kuupaev date,
            %4$s
        );$f$,

        replace(voter_list, ' ', ' + '),
        replace(voter_list, ' ', ', '),
        '',
        replace(voter_list, ' ', ' integer, ') || ' integer'  -- 4.
    ));
end; $do$;

select * from pivot;
```

Postgres 9.1 is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use double quotes. Because you are using spaces to identify column separators, you should remove spaces from column names (or change the way of separators identification).

With

```
...
select saledate as kuupaev,
  format ('"%s"', replace (upper(productname), ' ', '')) as tootjakood, 
  sum(quantity)::int as kogus 
from sales
...
```

you'll get:

```
  kuupaev   | /3,2M- | +-3,4%/3MM | O12.3/3MM 
------------+--------+------------+-----------
 2016-01-01 |        |         52 |         2
 2016-01-03 |    246 |            |          
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. There is related question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35266931/returning-empty-data-from-dynamic-pivot-is-there-is-no-data